# Keeping the same rhcloud url after migration from openshift v2 to openshift v3

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am using openshift online v2 default urls in my games. (appname.domainname.**rhcloud.com**) to reach the backend services running on openshift v2 instances.

Currently I need to move to opensift online v3 and I want this transition to be seamless for the players. Is there a way to be able to keep the same url after migration?

Since the default urls are RedHat Managed URLs I think it is not possible to manage them via the new Router plugin in v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not possible. I contact openshift support and they reply this:

[Openshift public url app (migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923453/openshift-public-url-app-migration)

"Unfortunately, we are unable to provide the same URLs that you have used previously. You would have to recompile your applications with new URLs following a migration."

Comment: Thank you. I got the same reply from support. Unfortunately that is not a wise decision given by RedHat. Leaves us in trouble. I had to think a severe    transform effort to the new url.