# Openshift public url app (migration)

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-cartridge

Would be possible, when migrating from Openshift 2 to 3, to keep the xxx.rhcloud.com url? Anybody knows if Red Hat is providing some solution? O maybe some kind of redirection would work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As they even shut down v2 with a notice period of 1 month i would not expect anything. You have to use your own domain if you want control.

Comment: Thanks Roland, thats my guess too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed by Openshift Support:

"Unfortunately, we are unable to provide the same URLs that you have used previously. You would have to recompile your applications with new URLs following a migration."